# Find innerText after an element

Tags: javascript, css

**HTML**

`<div class="price"><strike>AAA</strike>BBB</div>`

My question is if there is any way to grab only the "BBB" text, using JS. Note that **I don't have any access to the HTML code.**

I need to grab both texts (AAA and BBB) separately.

For example `document.querySelector('.price strike').innerText` which returns "AAA"

For the second part I use `document.querySelector('.price').innerText` which will returns "AAABBB". That's the problem. Is there any way to select directly the "BBB"?

Comment: probably do substring to get 'BBB', from 'AAABBB'.substr('AAA'.length)

Comment: why don't you wrap BBB in a span tag, then select it??

Comment: you need to iterate over just the text nodes in the element you are interested in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your specific case 'BBB' is the last child of '.price' so you can get it's value as simple as:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.price').lastChild.nodeValue;
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div class="price"><strike>AAA</strike>BBB</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is any method to get this 'no strike' text directly, but you can achieve what you want with a little workaround. For example playing with the `slice` and `indexOf` methods:

```js
const strikeText = document.querySelector('.price strike').innerText;
const allText = document.querySelector('.price').innerText;

const restText = allText.slice(allText.indexOf(strikeText) + strikeText.length)

console.log(strikeText)
console.log(restText)
```

```html
<div class="price"><strike>AAA</strike>BBB</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the child nodes and add node values from text nodes

```
function getNodeText(elem) {
  var txt = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (elem.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) { //text node
      txt += elem.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
    }
  }
}
```